# Adding headings to table columns, and outputting a total from SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this code,

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
    echo "<b>Sales for {$therecord['firstname']} {$therecord['lastname']}</b>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
        echo "<table><tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row['product']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['quantity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['cost']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

$sqltotal = mysql_query(
    "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
echo "<b>Total Owing: {$sqltotal}</b>";
```

I would like to add a heading to each table column, and maybe some spacing between them.

How would I go about that?

Additionally, I am trying to use the SQL SUM function and output a total, but at the moment it outputs something like #id24 instead...

Comment: The mysql extension is in a state of obsolescence. Use the mysqli extension instead.

Comment: @Artefacto: ...preferably with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could echo the table headings before the while loop;

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Quantity:</th>
        <th>Cost:</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
$sqlstr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
    ....
}
....
?>
```

This would sort your SUM issue (using mysql_result). Currently you are only outputting the resource.

```
$sqltotal = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'"),0);
echo "<b>Total Owing: {$sqltotal}</b>";
```

Comment: I posted i reply but I Misread the question :/ This answer is more applicable!

Answer (score 2):

Just echo it before you start the `while` loop:

```
echo '<tr><th>Name:</th><th>Quantity:</th><th>Cost:</th></tr>';
```

As for your sum problem, it's because you are echoing the resource ID. You also need to call `mysql_fetch_array()` (or similar function) on that resource as well like you did with the other one.

Answer (score 2):

For totals,Instead of running a second query, just dump the cost to a temporary variable and increment while looping thru the query array...

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
    echo "<b>Sales for {$therecord['firstname']} {$therecord['lastname']}</b>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
        echo "<table><tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row['product']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['quantity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['cost']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        $_t += $row['cost'];
    }
}
echo "<b>Total Owing: {$_t}</b>";
```

Cons:
You only get the total value after the loop finished..

For headings.. just print them before the loop..

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlstr = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) {
    echo "<b>Sales for {$therecord['firstname']} {$therecord['lastname']}</b>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) {
        echo "<table><tr>";
        echo "<td>{$row['product']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['quantity']}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$row['cost']}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
echo "<b>Total Owing: ".mysql_num_rows($sqlstr)."</b>";
```

**Just have to run the number or rows as the query is the same as above!**

Comment: By default, `mysql_fetch_array` allows both numeric and associative access. It defaults to `MYSQL_BOTH` for the return type.

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` is not the answer this will only return the number of rows and not the sum of the cost.

Answer (score 0):

about the sum :
after run query , you need to  get the result

```
$sqltotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cost) as total FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltotal);
            echo "<b>Total Owing: {$row['total']}</b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlstr = mysql_query( 
    "SELECT * FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'"); 
if (mysql_numrows($sqlstr) != 0) { 
    echo "<b>Sales for {$therecord['firstname']} {$therecord['lastname']}</b>"; 
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<th>Product</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Quantity</th>"; 
    echo "<th>Cost</th>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlstr)) { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td>{$row['product']}</td>"; 
        echo "<td>{$row['quantity']}</td>"; 
        echo "<td>{$row['cost']}</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    $sqltotal = mysql_query( 
        "SELECT SUM(cost) AS Total FROM sales where passport = '{$therecord['passport']}'"); 
    $totalRow = mysql_fetch_array($sqltotal)) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\"></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>Total Owing: {$totalRow['Total']}</b></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 

    echo "</table>"; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for the sum:

```
$sqltotal = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(cost) AS totalcost FROM sales WHERE passport = '" . mysql_real_esacpe_string($therecord['passport] . "';
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqltotal);
echo "<b>Total Owing: {$row['totalcost']}</b>";
```